# How to add spark.executor.extraClassPath in spark-conf using bootsrap action in EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, emr

I am trying to load data from Netezza to AWS. I want to add spark.executor.extraClassPath and spark.driver.extraClassPath in spark-defaults.conf in bootstrap action. Please find below updconf.sh(Bootstrap action)

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/nzjdbc.jar /usr/lib/sqoop/lib/ --sse aws:kms --sse-kms-key-id 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
echo "updating spark-defaults.conf"
sudo chmod 777 /home/hadoop/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
sudo echo >> /home/hadoop/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
driverstr='/usr/lib/sqoop/lib/nzjdbc.jar' 
sudo echo "export spark.executor.extraClassPath=`echo $driverstr`">>/home/hadoop/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
sudo echo "export spark.driver.extraClassPath=`echo $driverstr`">>/home/hadoop/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

But I am getting '/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf: No such file or directory' error. 
How can I do this?

Comment: bootstrap actions run before EMR software is installed.  That is why spark-defaults.conf is not there.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this. Simplest one is as below:

1. Create a file called myConfig.json

   ```
   'Configurations': [
               {
                   'Classification': 'spark-defaults',
                   "Properties":
                   {
                       "spark.executor.extraClassPath": "value for executorsclasspath",
                       "spark.driver.extraClassPath": "value for driver classpath",
                       "spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts": "...",
   ....
   ....//other properties as you need.
                   }
               },
           ]
   ```
2. Upload the file to S3 bucket.
3. While creating the cluster from the console, just provide the location for the file in S3 in "Edit software settings".

[image: step 1 in cluster creation.]

4. Provide other parameters as you need and create cluster.

Moreover, you can also use any of the AWS SDK like CLI or Python and provide these config parameters.

Reference : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html